# How to select half precision (BFLOAT16 vs FLOAT16) for your trained model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, half-precision-float

how will you decide what precision works best for your inference model? Both BF16 and F16 takes two bytes but they use different number of bits for fraction and exponent.

Range will be different but I am trying to understand why one chose one over other.

Thank you

```
    |--------+------+----------+----------|
    | Format | Bits | Exponent | Fraction |
    |--------+------+----------+----------|
    | FP32   |   32 |        8 |       23 |
    | FP16   |   16 |        5 |       10 |
    | BF16   |   16 |        8 |        7 |
    |--------+------+----------+----------|

Range
bfloat16: ~1.18e-38 … ~3.40e38 with 3 significant decimal digits.
float16:  ~5.96e−8 (6.10e−5) … 65504 with 4 significant decimal digits precision.
```

Comment: I think float16 is used for gpu whereas bfloat16 is used for tpu mp during training.

Comment: @M.Innat Ampere GPUs support bfloat16: https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/Data-Center/a100/pdf/a100-80gb-datasheet-update-nvidia-us-1521051-r2-web.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bfloat16` is generally easier to use, because it works as a drop-in replacement for `float32`. If your code doesn't create `nan/inf` numbers or turn a non-`0` into a `0` with `float32`, then it shouldn't do it with `bfloat16` either, roughly speaking. So, if your hardware supports it, I'd pick that.

Check out [AMP](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) if you choose `float16`.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to know what you would pick if hardware supports both..

Comment: @RedFox `bfloat16`, as my answer mentions at the end. (You probably read it before I wrote that part)

Comment: Thanks. They do offer different range of numbers. Wondering if this range is the reason to chose one over other. ps: updated the question with range.